# Schengen Visa for two stopover in Germany?

Tags: schengen

I'm a Indian Citizen staying in the US (with valid US visa) and I am Planning to travel to India with two stopovers in Germany (only connecting flight in Frankfurt & Munich). Do I need a Schengen visa for travel?

Comment: To clarify, am I right in thinking that you'll enter Germany in Frankfurt, fly on a domestic flight to Munich, then leave Germany from there?

Comment: See http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/17385/is-a-schengen-visa-transit-visa-required-for-transit-flight-from-vienna-to-frank/17391#17391 and http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/12762/do-i-need-an-airport-transit-visa-for-germany-if-i-have-a-schengen-visa