# Layover at Dusseldorf and Frankfurt, category A or B visa?

Tags: visas, transit, layovers, dusseldorf, frankfurt

I am a Indian citizen in the United States on a F-1 visa.

For the summer break, I am traveling (round-trip) from Chicago to New Delhi via Dusseldorf-Frankfurt by Lufthansa airlines. My onward Journey would be on July - 8 and return Journey on Aug - 11.

My layover will be of 1 hour 10 mins in Frankfurt and 3 hours in Dusseldorf.

I would like to know if I require Category A or Category B Visa. If not, what type of visa do I require for the Schengen visa for my transit. How I can apply for the same?

I tried to find slots in German consulate but all slots are full before my departure date. If I don't get the Schengen visa, I cannot travel and will loose all the fare (since my ticket is a non-refundable ticket). Is there any other way I can tackle this situation.

Comment: Possible duplicate - [Schengen Visa for two stopover in Germany?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/22614/schengen-visa-for-two-stopover-in-germany?lq=1), Related - [Is a Schengen visa/transit visa required for transit flight from Vienna to Frankfurt?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/17385/is-a-schengen-visa-transit-visa-required-for-transit-flight-from-vienna-to-frank/17391#17391)

Comment: Which city are you applying for the visa from? Also, please consider posting only 1 question in 1 post. Split multiple questions across different posts.

Comment: Here's the form with item No. 21 - http://www.vfs-germany.co.in/NewDelhi_NorthIndia/Pdf/Schengen_visa_application_Form_250912.pdf as the **Transit** and _not_ Airport Transit.

Answer (score 7):

As explained in [Is a Schengen visa/transit visa required for a transit flight through two Schengen airports?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/17385/is-a-schengen-visa-transit-visa-required-for-transit-flight-from-vienna-to-frank) you will not be able to stay in the international area of the airport. As you will go through a passport check and enter the Schengen area, an “airport transit visa” (type A) is definitely not enough and you need to apply for a regular uniform Schengen visa. On the form cross “transit” as the purpose of your trip (and *not* “airport transit”).

Unfortunately, if the German consulate covering your area is not able to offer an appointment or issue a visa in time, there is not much you can do. You can always try to contact someone at the consulate to see if there is still some way to set up an appointment but it seems unlikely they would make an exception.

You could also try to contact the airline and hope they refund the ticket anyway but they most likely don't have to (conditions of carriage typically specify that securing all required visas is the passenger's responsibility).

Alternatively, you could try to change your connection to have only one stop in the Schengen area (i.e. find direct flights from Chicago to Frankfurt and from Frankfurt to New Delhi or even to another US or Indian destination). It will probably cost you more and you will have to pay some change fees on top of the ticket price but you might be able to save your trip and avoid losing all the money you already paid. Since you would still be flying with Lufthansa, they might be more willing to accommodate you.

If you have only one stop at a German airport and direct flights out of the Schengen area, you won't need a visa at all if you have a valid US visa.

Comment: In addition to direct flights you might consider changes in the UK or non-schengen eastern european countries as a way to avoid the "two schengen stops in a row" problem.

Answer (score 5):

Check the two links which were posted as comment to the question. Since you are entering the Schengen Region in order to take the flight from Dusseldorf to Frankfurt or vice versa, you will need a Uniform Schengen visa which was earlier Category C, the [Category B Schengen Visa](http://www.immihelp.com/visas/schengenvisa/) has been discontinued.

To apply for the visa, you can check this [website for VFS Global](http://www.vfs-germany.co.in/NewDelhi_NorthIndia/visaapplyingprocess.html) which handles the visa applications for Germany in India.

Comment: Don't think it makes much of a difference in practice but I believe that “type B” visas do not exist anymore, you need a regular uniform visa (“type C”) from Germany.

Comment: @Relaxed Was not aware of this. Fixed.

Comment: One should also be aware the the "flight" from Dusseldorf to Frankfurt might well be a train. This certainly requires a visa...

Comment: @KristvanBesien Certainly, but the OP mentions Lufthansa airlines with specific layovers hence I specifically mentioned a flight, but a train would require a visa would as well, largely obvious.

Comment: @AdityaSomani The surprising thing is that Lufthansa also sells train connections with a Lufthansa flight number. Don't know about Frankfurt-Düsseldorf, though.

Comment: @Relaxed You learn something new everyday! I never knew they could do that. Do others do it as well?

Comment: @AdityaSomani [Air France](http://www.airfrance.fr/FR/en/common/resainfovol/avion_train/reservation_avion_train_strasbourg_airfrance.htm) does something similar as well (in both cases you check-in at the train station but you need to take care of your luggage yourself).

Comment: @Relaxed About half of the LH connections between FRA and DUS are operated by Deutsche Bahn. The connections operated by LH have the numbers LH07x or LH08x, and take about 50 minutes scheduled. The connections operated by DBAG have flight numbers LH36xx and take between 1:12 and 1:25 or so, and leave Frankfurt from Terminal N.