# Schengen visa for two stop overs in Germany? I do have a valid F1 visa for US

Tags: visas, schengen

I am travelling to USA from India and I have two layovers in Germany (Frankfurt and Dusseldorf). Do I need a transit visa or a Schengen visa?

Will I be exempted from Schengen visa, since I hold a valid f1 visa?

Comment: This is the third time the same question has been asked within one week (visa required when flying from US to India via Düsseldorf and Frankfurt?).

Comment: Maybe there's a sale on with a really good fare for this combination?

Answer (score 1):

You will need a full Schengen visa

The reason for this is that the flight between Frankfurt and Dusseldor is a normal domestic German flight. As such, you will have to enter the Schengen area at the first airport, take the domestic flight, then exit Schengen to board your second.

If you had an international-internationl connection, eg India to X, X to the USA, then holding a US visa can often allow you to transit without needing a special transit visa. (Depends on the country, airport and if it's two tickets or one).

However, if you have to take an intra-Schengen flight as one of the legs, then that means you have to enter the Schengen area, which means you need a regular short stay Schengen visa. Assuming you're doing the same things on a return flight, you'd need a multiple entry visa as you'd have to enter and exit Schengen on each direction. If it's just a one-way flight from India to the USA, then a single entry Schengen visa is fine

Comment: Sorry, but I am still left with one last question. What type of Schengen visa should apply for? there are different categories such as tourist, business, visiting etc on the vfs website. None of them suite my requirement.

Comment: As explained in [this answer to a similar question](http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/30373/26), you'll need to apply for a Short Term Tourist visa, which is called a Regular Uniform Visa (used to be called “type C”)

Comment: @Santhosh There is just one type of visa, only different purposes and “transit” is one of them (“transit” is distinct from “airport transit”, which would be another type of visa).

Comment: (+1) For a return trip, most travellers are more likely to get a two-entry visa rather than a multiple entry visa.

Comment: @Relaxed Thank you for the information, do I have a separate check list(will I be exempted from health/travel insurance). If someone can provide an official link for the checklist, it would be deeply appreciated.