# Do I need a visa for layover at Germany airport?

Tags: schengen, transit, germany

I got a single-entry Schengen visa. After attending a forum at Germany, I will go to the UK for few days. But I am supposed to take my flight back to my country, Myanmar, from Germany. So I will fly back from London to the German airport to take my flight. Will I still need a visa there although I will not go inside Germany again?

Comment: Related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/12762/do-i-need-an-airport-transit-visa-for-germany-if-i-have-a-schengen-visa?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

There is some inconsitency that is published by the German diplomatic missions as far as visas are concerned so here goes:

- [From UK](http://www.london.diplo.de/Vertretung/london/en/07/03__Visa/014__Airport__transit.html) - You don't need a visa if you hold a valid visa for USA, UK, Canada, Japan, etc. and generally Myanmark is not mentioned as a country needing airport transit visa.
- [From US](http://www.germany.info/Vertretung/usa/en/05__Legal/02__Directory__Services/01__Visa/__Transit__Visa.html) - You do need a transit visa as a citizen of Myanmar but if you hold a valid visa for US or are returning from US having used your visa.
- and finally from [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=1&HEALTH=1&NA=MM&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=MM&EM=GB&TR=DE&VT=00&user=STAR&subuser=STARB2C#), which airlines use to make their determination - if your Visa for the UK will still be valid by the time you transit on your way back to Myanmar you should not need a transit visa.

Save these you will need a transit visa on your way back.  Also all of this is conditional on you transiting through one of 6 airports in Germany (Cologne/Bonn, Munich, Dusseldorf, Frankfurt, Berlin, or Hamburg) and don't have another stop in between in a different Schengen country.

Having said all that it might be a good idea to contact a German consulate to get the information directly since the published information on their consulate pages is somewhat inconsistent.

Comment: I think the German embassy in Myanmar should be the most up-to-date regarding [requirements for citizens of Myanmar](http://www.rangun.diplo.de/Vertretung/rangun/en/01-willkommen-in-D/02-Visabestimmungen/Visabestimmungen.html). Its information is also [in line with the list on the EU's official website](http://ec.europa.eu/dgs/home-affairs/e-library/documents/policies/borders-and-visas/visa-policy/docs/annex_7b_atv-national_lists.en.pdf) so I think it's safe to assume that a visa is indeed required (save for the usual exemptions). Also, the “and” in your second bullet point should be an “or”.